# TimeZone.GetUtcOffset() Requires DateTime, but DateTime's Timezone is Ignored, why?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

My goal is to get the difference between UTC and another time zone.  Take for example the difference between UTC and EST (UTC-5:00).  Also for sake of example assume my system is currently in Pacific Standard Time so DateTime.Kind, "LOCAL", is PST.  In order to find the difference between UTC and EST I'm forced to provide a DateTime which I'm providing in PST.   Here's a simplified snippet of my code:

```
    public static void Run_Timezone_Test()
    {
        var myDate = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(myDate.Kind);
        //OUTPUT: Local (note this is currently PST)

        var easternTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
        var offset = easternTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(myDate);
        Console.WriteLine(offset);
        //OUTPUT: -05:00:00 (correct offset for EST)

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Why am I forced to provide "myDate" if it and its time zone are not used?

Comment: Refer to the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), which explains (among other things) that "Time Zone != Offset".

Comment: @MattJohnson, great article, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of why it matters:

```
var AUSEast = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
var offset = AUSEast.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
Console.WriteLine(offset);

offset = AUSEast.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6));
Console.WriteLine(offset);
```

At the time of writing, this will output (assuming you have AEST installed as a system time - you can check via `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`):

```
11:00:00
10:00:00
```

Note that a time zone does *not* indicate an offset from UTC by itself. Time anomalies (most commonly daylight savings) will change the UTC offset while still remaining in the same time zone